# reactjs cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach, reactjs

i am getting the products array from a parent element and trying to loop through it using forEach. instead i am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at ProductTable.render". the console.log(rows) outputs the array of objects though.

below is my ProductTable component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {ProductCategoryRow}  from './productcategoryrow.js';
import {ProductRow} from './productrow.js'

export class ProductTable extends React.Component {    
    render(){
       let rows =[];
       let lastcategory = null;
       this.props.products.forEach(function(product){

            if(product.category !== lastcategory){
                rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category = {product.category} key={product.category}/>);
            }
            rows.push(<ProductTable product={product} key={product.name}/>);
            lastcategory = product.category;

       });
       console.log(rows);
       return(
           <div>
             <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>

                        {rows}

                </thead>
             </table>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

below is it's parent component from where the props are being passed:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {SearchBar} from './searchbar.js';
import {ProductTable} from './producttable.js';


class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
          <div>
          <SearchBar/>
          <ProductTable products = {this.props.products}/>
          </div>
      );
  }
}

var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];


ReactDOM.render(<FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `forEach` loop you do:

```
<ProductTable product={product} key={product.name}/>
```

Note that you are setting the prop `product`. `ProductTable` however expects the prop `products`.

Since the value of the variable `product` is not an array and since you are not using `ProductRow` anywhere I can only assume you meant to use

```
<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name}/>
```

(`ProductRow` instead of `ProductTable`) instead.